# Excel vba 2013 not supporting thisworkbook.sheets syntax

Tags: excel, listview, vba

**Background**

I am working on a inventory management and staff time tracker tool in which I have created several tabs i.e Login Panel, Interface, Reference tab, ... etc.
In the VBA editor in thisworkbook module of this tool file I have written a code within the workbook_beforeClose event which will hide all the sheets and make the Login Panel sheet visible before getting closed whenever user tried to close it. Here is the code:-

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
sht_LoginPanel.Visible = xlSheetVisible
For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
If sht.Name <> "Login Panel" Then
sht.Visible = xlSheetHidden
End If
Next sht
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

**Problem**

This above piece of code is written on a computer with MS Excel 2010 and everything works fine. However when I use this tool on a computer with MS Excel 2013 the same above code gives me error on line 5 *(If sht.Name <>...)*.
Another amazing thing which I caught is error does not occurs with the first iteration of the For each loop... it only occurs when it has reached till *Next sht* command line and then comes back to line 5.

Can anybody please help me with this error and explain what is wrong here.... also is there any compatibility issue between Excel VBA 2010 and 2013. Also one last thing is I also see the ListView control is not working in 2013 wheareas it was working perfectly fine in excel 2010.

Please help....

Regards,
Premanshu

Comment: Did any of the answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Could you switch to this and see if it helps?

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  sht_LoginPanel.Visible = xlSheetVisible
  For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    If sht <> sht_LoginPanel Then
      sht.Visible = xlSheetHidden
    End If
  Next sht
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Regarding compatibility issues, the only forward-compatibility problem I've come across so far is that in the 64 bit version of excel 2013 (and apparently 2016) activeX objects break any code that refers to them.  Apparently they are not going to be supported going forward or something.

Comment: I tried your code and it worked perfectly fine. For the activeX controls it will be really bad if they stop supporting them. A lot of excel based tools are based on them.

Comment: @Premanshu We made the decision to stop using them all together a while ago thankfully.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me in all Excel versions 2010, 2013, and 2016. BUT: If there is no sheet named "Login Panel" you would try to hide ALL sheets which is not possible, at least one sheet mus remain unhidden. Also I strongly recommend to initialize variables and use indentations - makes life and maintenance easier. This codes works on all Excel platforms - I have tried it out:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
  ' create variables with data type
  Dim sht As Worksheet
  Dim sht_LoginPanel As Worksheet

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Set sht_LoginPanel = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Login Panel")
  sht_LoginPanel.Visible = xlSheetVisible
  For Each sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    If sht.Name <> "Login Panel" Then
      ' prevents an error if you try to hide the last worksheet
      On Error Resume Next
      sht.Visible = xlSheetHidden
      ' go back to normal error handling
      On Error GoTo 0
    End If
  Next sht
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Moos,

thank you so much for your response. However I used the code suggested by Brent and it worked fine. Thanks again. I really appreciate it.